# What is the simplest way of filling in a map within a map that contains `std::variant` in C++?

Tags: c++

So I want to have a variable that is of type `map < string, map<string, variant<bool, vector<int>>> > args`.

How can one go about filling this in, not just on the first level (i.e. the first map) but the second level (i.e. the second map) which in fact is of type `std::variant` which doesn't support the typical `args['level1']['level2']`?

I have tried using a for loop, looping over a vector of strings, but i'm not sure this is going anywhere:

```
    for (unsigned i=0; i<objects.size(); i++) {
        
        // Create the obj_dict
        obj_dict.insert({objects.at(i), })
        obj_dict.insert({"Missing", false})
        obj_dict.insert({"Obstructed", false})
        obj_dict.insert({"Moved", false})
        obj_dict.insert({"Gone", false})
    }
```

P.S This is what it would ideally look like,

```
    map < string, map<string, variant<bool, vector<int>>> > args{
        {"Head", {
            {"coords", {1,2,3}},
            {"missing", false},
            {"obstructed", false},
            {"moved", false},
            {"gone", false},
        }},
        {"Arm", {
            {"coords", {1,2,3}},
            {"missing", false},
            {"obstructed", false},
            {"moved", false},
            {"gone", false}
        }}
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that braced initialization lists will not survive a trip through a forwarding reference that's used to construct a variant.

You'll have to be a little bit more explicit:

```
#include <variant>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::map <std::string, std::map<std::string,
                std::variant<bool,
                         std::vector<int>>> > args{
        {"Head", {
            {"coords", std::vector<int>{1,2,3}},
            {"missing", false},
            {"obstructed", false},
            {"moved", false},
            {"gone", false},
        }},
        {"Arm", {
            {"coords", std::vector<int>{1,2,3}},
            {"missing", false},
            {"obstructed", false},
            {"moved", false},
            {"gone", false}
        }}
    };
```

Comment: Aha, I figured i'd be missing something. Would you mind also pointing me in the direction of how would one would also traverse (i.e. extract `key/value` pairs) a layered map with a variant?

Comment: `for (const auto &[key,val]: map)` is the simplest way to traverse an associative container. So `for (const auto &[key,inner_map] : args)` to iterate over the outer map, and inside that for loop `for (const auto &[name, value]: inner_map)` to iterate over each inner map. Mission accomplished.